# Result always true?

Tags: delphi

I am trying to return a value of a function to tell me if a location has Lava or Water at that location.

The issue is Even if it has lava or water there, it still returns true.
The values for water,lava,and fly are from a players creature's list. It is just getting if that creature has the ability of water,lava,or can fly. And i just mark them as true /false accordingly.. Position is a TPOINT. It loads all this into a function and as long as the function CheckLocation returns true then its ok location

```
  if FMyPlayers.Player[i].Values['water']='yes' then
       canwater := true;
   if FMyPlayers.Player[i].Values['Lava']='yes' then
       canlava := true;
   if FMyPlayers.Player[i].Values['fly']='yes' then
       canfly := true;
   cansnow := true;
   if checkLocation(position,cansnow,canlava,canwater,canfly) = False then
      exit;

function TBaseGameForm.checkLocation(position :Tpoint;Cansnow,canlava,canwater,canfly:bool):Bool;
begin
RESULT := True;
if canfly = true then
   RESULT := true
else begin
  if FGamePlay.waterLocations.IndexOfName('x'+inttostr(Position.x)+inttostr(Position.Y)) <> -1 then begin    //Check location
     Showmessage('Cant move there due to water');
     RESULT := FALSE;
   end;
  if FGamePlay.LavaLocations.IndexOfName('x'+inttostr(Position.x)+inttostr(Position.Y)) <> -1 then begin    //Check location
     Showmessage('Cant move there due to lava');
     RESULT := False;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

when running i check the values in the WaterLocations

```
[0]  x47
[1]  y47
[2]  x58
[3]  y58
```

The value of Position.x and Position.y are (4,7)  Thus it should return false cause x47 is on the list.

Comment: I'm not familiar with delphi/Pascal, but does capitalization have any meaning? (`True` vs. `true`, `FALSE` vs `False`)

Comment: Your list have to have an entry like 'x47=...' for `IndexOfName('x47')` to not to return '-1' (assuming NameValueSeparator is '='). If this is not so, just use `IndexOf`.

Comment: What happens at positions `(22, 22)` and `(222, 2)`? I think your location storage needs improvement...

Comment: BTW, you don't need `if canfly ..`, the 'result' is already true. I believe you probably want your function to look like: `Result:=canfly;` `if not Result then begin ..`.

Comment: thanks for help, True vs true should not matter, will try indexof,  22,22 and 222,2 would retun a -1 due to it not being on the list? Right now Canfly is true as it may have more options for it later just for now its := true.

Comment: @sarnold is referring to the problem that `X=2,Y=222`, `X=22,Y=22` and `X=222,Y=2` are not distinquishable from each other using your current formatting in the lists because they would all be `x2222`. You need a clearer separation from X and Y.

Comment: @Remy: well said; better said than I did, any how. Thanks! :)

Comment: well if it matters, the most is 30 ,30  the x,y will never be bigger then 30 high or wide. So Dont think that can still be an issue, but very nice at finding that issue :D

Comment: What's with all the text data rather than numeric??

Comment: its being read in from an INI file, amoung other text.. found it easier to use just text? really no reason.. and yea i now see what you mean by 2,22 it would be same as 22,2 :D

Comment: The main error here is that you are concatenating different data into one variable ('x45'), where it should be stored in a structure containing 'x', '4' and '5'. These kinds of 'shortcuts' will get you into trouble as your program expands. The rules that we use for database normalization should also be applied to internal data structures.

Comment: -1  How can i improve this question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like @SertacAkyuz said, the problem is your use of `IndexOfName()`.  You need to use `IndexOf()` instead.

There is another bug in your `CheckLocation()` function.  You are ignoring all of the input parameters other than `canfly`.  If `canwater` or `canlava` were True, your function would return False on any water/lava location.  You need to check if the location actually matches the Player's capabilities.  If `canwater` is true, there is no need to check if the location is water.  Likewise with lava.

Try this instead:

```
canwater := (FMyPlayers.Player[i].Values['water'] = 'yes');
canlava := (FMyPlayers.Player[i].Values['Lava'] = 'yes');
canfly := (FMyPlayers.Player[i].Values['fly'] = 'yes'); 
cansnow := true; 
if not CheckLocation(position, cansnow, canlava, canwater, canfly) then 
  Exit;
```

.

```
function TBaseGameForm.CheckLocation(position: TPoint; cansnow, canlava, canwater, canfly: Boolean): Boolean; 
var
  loc: String;
begin 
  Result := True;
  if (not canfly) and ((not canwater) or (not canlava)) then
  begin
    loc := Format('x%d%d', [Position.X, Position.Y]);

    if (not canwater) and (FGamePlay.waterLocations.IndexOf(loc) <> -1) then
    begin
      Showmessage('Cant move there due to water'); 
      Result := False;
      Exit;
    end;

    if (not canlava) and (FGamePlay.LavaLocations.IndexOf(loc) <> -1) then
    begin
      Showmessage('Cant move there due to lava'); 
      Result := False;
      Exit;
    end;
  end; 
end;
```

With that said, I agree with @sarnold that your coordinate system needs some tweaking.  It is fine only as long as your x/y coordinates are both single digits.  But if they are multiple digit, it will not work.  At the very least, you should prefix the Y coordinates, eg:

```
[0]  x4y7
[1]  x5y8

loc := Format('x%dy%d', [Position.X, Position.Y]);
```

Personally, I wouldn't use a `TStrings` to hold integer values like this at all.  I would use a `TList` of `TPoint` instances instead, eg:

```
waterLocations: TList;

function FindLocation(List: TList; Position: TPoint): Integer;
begin
  for Result := 0 to List.Coun-1 do
  begin
    with PPoint(List[Result])^ do
    begin
      if (X = Position X) and (Y = Position.Y) then Exit;
    end;
  end;
  Result := -1;
end;
```

.

```
if (not canwater) and (FindLocation(FGamePlay.waterLocations, Position) <> -1) then
begin
  Showmessage('Cant move there due to water'); 
  Result := False;
  Exit;
end;
```

Or, if you are using a modern Delphi version that supports Generics, a `TList<TPoint>`:

```
waterLocations: TList<TPoint>;

function FindLocation(List: TList<TPoint>; Position: TPoint): Integer;
begin
  for Result := 0 to List.Coun-1 do
  begin
    with List[Result] do
    begin
      if (X = Position X) and (Y = Position.Y) then Exit;
    end;
  end;
  Result := -1;
end;
```

.

```
if (not canwater) and (FindLocation(FGamePlay.waterLocations, Position) <> -1) then
begin
  Showmessage('Cant move there due to water'); 
  Result := False;
  Exit;
end;
```

Or even a single `TDictionary` that stores the type of location that any given X/Y coordinate specifies:

```
type
  locType = (locLand, locWater, locLava, locSnow);

locations: TDictionary<TPoint, locType>;
```

.

```
function TBaseGameForm.CheckLocation(position: TPoint; cansnow, canlava, canwater, canfly: Boolean): Boolean; 
var
  loc: locType;
begin 
  Result := True;
  if not canfly then
  begin
    locations.TryGetValue(Position, loc);
    case loc of
      locWater: begin
        if not canwater then
        begin
          Showmessage('Cant move there due to water'); 
          Result := False;
        end;
      end;
      locLava: begin
        if not canlava then
        begin
          Showmessage('Cant move there due to lava'); 
          Result := False;
          Exit;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end; 
end;
```

Comment: thanks i will give this a try , currently at work so only have a quick second to look at it :D

Comment: Figured i would ask... According to this code if the unit CanFly = yes , thus being true... then it should be able to go on lava and water correct? i only ask cause its not working right for CanFly units... though i think it may be something else.

Comment: `CheckLocation()` should return `True` when `CanFly` is `True`, so I would suspect a problem outside of `CheckLocation()`.